# How to deselect an item in PySide QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyside

Really simple question, but I can't seem to see the answer in the docs.

I have a working QTableWidget and I have a need to clear the selection. The use case is when  adding a row to the datamodel I don't want the user to associate the new row with what was selected, hence the need to clear the selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might have forgotten to check the super classes of a QTableWidget.

QTableWidget -> QTableView -> [QAbstractItemView.clearSelection()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection)

If you need to control the selection state of a specific item:
[QTableWidget.setItemSelected()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidget.html#setItemSelected)

Edit: previous link broken. 
[PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.clearSelection()](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.clearSelection)

> PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.clearSelection()
>   Deselects all selected
>   items. The current index will not be changed.